# CNAME record on cPanel to point to Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, cpanel

We purchased and installed an SSL Certificate on our Heroku app, and install the SSL endpoint. The domain is using nameservers that point to a separate cPanel hosting account. I have tried to add a CNAME record in cPanel that points to our Heroku secure endpoint.

I setup the CNAME like this:

```
Name: *.domain.com.
Type: CNAME
Record: example-7245.herokussl.com
```

But is has been a whole day and the url still doesn't to heroku. Is this even possible to do this way? We need the email to run off the cpanel host so if we could just use a cname record for the domain server it was perfect.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but when I added the DNS add-on Zerigo DNS Zerigo Tier 1, it started to work.